# How to do relative imports on app engine? (python)

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to do a relative import in App Engine using python. Here is my basic situation:

```
app/
     models.py
     app.yaml
     /mymodule/
         test.py
         mymodule.yaml
```

I'm trying to import models.py.. basically I have the same datastore models that are being using across different modules, so I was hoping to be able to import models.py from within test.py (or any other module).

How do relative imports work with App Engine? Thanks.

**Edit**: My app.yaml file:

```
application: [my app name]
version: main
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

inbound_services:
- mail

builtins:
- appstats: on

handlers:

    [my handlers]

libraries:
- name: webapp2
  version: "2.5.1"

- name: jinja2
  version: latest

- name: markupsafe
  version: latest

- name: ssl
  version: latest
```

Comment: It's a bit confusing on how you presented your modules.. can you make a bit more clear and also show us where is your `app.yaml` in that structure?

Comment: Just tried to make it clearer -- does that help? Basically `app/` is my app's directory, which contains `models.py`,`app.yaml`, as well as the directory `/mymodule/`. Within the subdirectory `/mymodule/` is `test.py`, from which I am trying to import `models.py`.

Comment: You should include the handlers to see how you are using your files..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the solution is to put the `mymodule.yaml` under app. It seems that the root of your code in the `PYTHONPATH` is the directory where your module's `yaml` file is.

Comment: Up voted. I have the same problem as OP, and put module yaml file at top directory (instead of inside module directory) can fix this import issue. I just doubt why [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/#Python_Configuration) shows us this kind of directory hierarchy. Maybe all modules are independent without using any common code outside the module?

Answer (score 2):

Create one empty file under `app` called [`__init__.py`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) to transform your directory into a package and then you will be able to import like:

```
from app import models
```

And you might want to add the same file into your `mymodule` directory as well.

Comment: Okay, perfect, thanks! If I wanted to import a specific class from within models, would this be the correct syntax?

`from app import models.classThatIWant`

Comment: it would be `from app.models import classThatIWant` but I think it's better to import models and then using it in the code like `models.classThatIWant`, but that that's a preference...

Comment: I just tested this with App Engine and it doesn't work -- it says: `ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package`. I have `__init__.py` files in each directory I'm trying to do a relative import from..